# Problem reflecting live changes with bootstrapped React/Redux app

Tags: reactjs, vite, hot-reload

I'm returning to React and Redux apps after some time away, and I'm getting some unexpected behavior.

I've used the Redux template with the old create-react-app, plus the recommended `npx degit reduxjs/redux-templates/packages/vite-template-redux my-app`, to bootstrap the basic setup, and changes reflect fine after `npm start` or `npm run dev`.

That said, even removing complexities with a Redux store, stuff as simple as text changes requires a full kill and restart to reflect onscreen. I'm used to live reflection on file save, but I've tried all browsers with no luck. Is this a deprecated feature, or are there steps/options I could be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running the application on WSL Ubuntu's command line; it fires up a browser window on startup, but doesn't register changes made in my IDE. It works when I make changes whilst running the app in my WebStorm terminal.